# Stuck porting paperjs to react/nodejs

Tags: reactjs, paperjs

I'm trying to port some paperjs code into a new react application. But I ran into some limitations.

In HTML:
Currently I have 2 animation files in paperjs and for each one I have an HTML file which works with

In React : The following works

```
 componentDidMount() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    paper.setup(canvas);

   require('./Lesson_1.js');

  paper.view.draw();
}
```

In React : The problem

I need to dynamically change the argument into require() based on the user choice, ...BUT

```
const lesson = './Lesson_1.js';
require(lesson)
```

does not work as the require() function needs a literal !!

Question 1: Is there a workaround for this so I could require a lesson of my choice, since I may have many more lessons? React seems to ignore the script tags

Question 2: Since this component does not mount again when the user chooses another lesson, how do I clear the same canvas and reload a fresh lesson js file?

I have no problem, the way it works currently but porting to react is a problem. Someone suggested to be to keep running the old way and create an iframe in react to show the contents, but I was looking for a cleaner solution in react without dependencies to other programs.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible workaround mentioned in this [discussion](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391) is to use a switch statement.
Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-paper-switch) demonstrating the solution.

```
class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    paper.setup('canvas');

    const scriptToLoad = 'a';

    switch (scriptToLoad) {
      case 'a':
        require('./a.js');
        break;
      case 'b':
        require('./b.js');
        break;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for for quick response. I had seen this as a possible solution, but it really isn't practical since I will eventually be having around 2000 such files!

Comment: Since it has been over a month and I have not received a better solution, I am going to choose your answer as the accepted one. Thanks.